# Drupal: token parsing issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I've a parsing issue using Drupal tokens :

[order-shipping-phone]
[order-billing-address]

However there are not spaces/next line between the addresses components:

i.e.

```
Name SurnameStreet Streetname 1921013AX, CityCOUNTRY
```

How can I fix it ? I don't think the token itself is wrong.. or is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably line breaks there. HTML doesn't display linebreaks, so you'll need to run it through `nl2br` (or use the linebreak Drupal input filter).